# Fortran Array Size Allocation

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, allocation

I am looking to take data and create new arrays that are the same shape. However, I seem to be making Fortran unhappy with this syntax:

For instance I want to create an array that is the same size as the input data:

```
function allocate_size(input_data)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL, INTENT(in) :: input_data
    REAL, DIMENSION(SIZE(input_data, DIM=1), SIZE(input_data, DIM=2), SIZE(input_data, DIM=3), SIZE(input_data, DIM=4), &
        SIZE(input_data, DIM=5)) :: new_data
end function allocate_size
```

or one that is slightly different when one of those SIZE(input_data, DIM=x) would be replaced with an integer. Is this an incorrect approach?

Comment: Yes, that's an incorrect approach.  As written `input_data` is scalar (it has no `dimension`) so attempts to apply `size` to it are nugatory.  If I understood what you are trying to do I might be able to provide assistance, but I don't.

Comment: Also, the type of `allocate_size` is not defined.

Comment: The goal of what I am doing is to read in some multi dimensional data, and then take an average along an axis. In some cases, I only want certain indices along an axis to be averaged, so I would like to allocate arrays with the filtered (indices wanted) data, the move the data into the allocated array, sum along an axis, and divide by the axis length that was summed on

Comment: Don't put important material in comments, edit your question so that it properly explains matters.